# Oracle Regexp - replace surrounding backets, but not inner string

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to take the following string...

```
v VARCHAR2(100) := '<LABEL> FOR ABC';
```

And turn it into...

```
'LABEL FOR ABC'
```

Which seemed easy, but I can't get this done in one regexp statement. The <...> block will always start the string.

For example, my best attempt....

```
v := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v, '[^\<][A-Z]+[^\>][A-Z ]+')
```

Yields 'LABEL'.

I did manage to get this working by doing the following...

```
v := REGEXP_REPLACE(v, '^\<');
v := REGEXP_REPLACE(v, '\>', 1, 1);
```

But I was wondering if this would be possible to be done in a single regexp statement.

Thanks

Edit: I forgot to mention, I only want to remove the leading <...>. If the string was something like

```
<LABEL> FOR ABC <LEAVE ME>
```

I would want it to be...

```
LABEL FOR ABC <LEAVE ME>
```

Comment: just replace `<` or `>` with null string. Yor regex would be `[><]`

Comment: What should happen for strings like "<>LAB><EL>" or ">><L>>><<<<AB<<EL>" or some other unconstrained string with non-matching braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE('<LABEL> FOR ABC <LEAVE ME>','^<(.*?)>','\1')`.

Pattern:

```
^<    --matches '<' at the beginning of the string.
.*?   --non greedy quantifier to match 0 or more characters within '<' and '>'. 
      --This is enclosed in brackets to form first capture group.
      --This is then used in replace_string as \1.
>     --Matches the first '>' after the first '<'.
```

Example:

```
SELECT '<LABEL> FOR ABC <LEAVE ME>' str,
       REGEXP_REPLACE ('<LABEL> FOR ABC <LEAVE ME>', '^<(.*?)>', '\1') replaced_str
  FROM DUAL;

str                         replaced_str
----------------------------------------------------
<LABEL> FOR ABC <LEAVE ME>  LABEL FOR ABC <LEAVE ME>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want to replace all instances of `<`and `>`with an empty string? Then this:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE('<LABEL> blah', '[<>]', '') FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Ideally it would only grab the first set, so that '<LABEL> FOR ABC <LEAVE ME>' would be 'LABEL FOR ABC <LEAVE ME>'